# Spring + Tiles how to use EL in tiles.xml

Tags: java, spring, el, tiles

I have tiles set up in my spring project as the view handler like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'd like to use EL to access the session scope inside tiles.xml, for resolving a jsp file name. This should be possible if i use CompleteAutoloadTilesContainerFactory, as described here:

http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/el-support.html

How can I set my spring tiles configuration to allow this. Ive tried using EL as it is currently set up but the EL is not parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, i left the configuration exactly the same and just included tiles-el.jar . No need to include tiles-extras.jar though. NFV

Answer (score 0):

You may try setting completeAutoload property of TilesConfigurer class. Please see reference doc [TilesConfirurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles2/TilesConfigurer.html).

This may require Tiles-Extras 2.2 jar file.

Comment: Yeah, i had noticed that setting and tried setting up the bean to set this to true. I didnt understand what to do about what it says in the note:

NOTE: Specifying the complete-autoload mode effectively disables all other bean properties on this configurer. The entire initialization procedure is then left to CompleteAutoloadTilesInitializer.

I ran the project anyway and keep getting this exception:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.servlet.wildcard.WildcardServletTilesApplicationContext