# apache tiles: expression language stopped to work with maven

Tags: jsp, maven, el, tiles

I had a spring-3.2.1/tiles-3.0.1 project where I had expression language working with tiles. This means that expressions such as `${jukebox.name}` worked in tile attribute expressions (and printed `Metal Jukebox` for example). This is my `tiles.xml` file:

```
<definition name="t.jukebox" extends="t.base">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/jukebox.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="title" expression="${jukebox.name} - lyricsBase"/>
</definition>

<definition name="t.song" extends="t.base">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/song.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="title" expression="${song.title} - ${song.author} in ${jukebox.name}"/>
</definition>

<definition name="t.static/about" extends="t.base">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/static/about.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="title" value="lyricsBase: about"/>
</definition>
```

My controllers look like the following - an object is passed to the layout and it has some certain getter methods (e.g. getName()):

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws Exception {
    return new ModelAndView("t.jukebox", "jukebox", facade);
}
```

Everything was working fine. Recently, I decided to move to maven. After all work is done, all dependencies fixed and builds are successful, I lost the dynamic tiles expressions functionality and I can't find the reason. Some people suggest to add

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

to the page, but I don't know where exactly. To the base tile layout or to the child? I've got one include.jsp, included by all jsp files, where I have all taglibs, but adding `elignored=false` didn't help.

It's probable that Maven has nothing to do with all this, I just don't know where to look for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it had something to do with maven though. I forgot to add a dependency on [tiles-el.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-el). But no exception was thrown - and this make it difficult to spot the problem. Thanks to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237155/769384)